# Dynamic name variable java (parser creating a structure)

Tags: java, class, variables, dynamic, linked-list

as far as I have read everywhere you can't create variables with a dynamic name in Java so I'll explain the problem to see if there is an alternative. My problem is that I have to parse a long text containing laws in english, wich has a hierarchy:

It is divided in this way:

Books

----Chapters

--------Articles
OR

Books

----Titles

--------Chapters

-------------Articles
OR

Books

----Titles

--------Chapters

-------------Sections

-----------------Articles

As you can tell it deppends on the sittuation the structure must vary. The info must be taken from a file like this:

Book 1: name of book one
Title 1: Name of title one
Chapter 1: Name of chapter 1
Article 1: name of article 1
Article 2: name of article 2
Chapter 2: name of chapter 2
Section 1: name of section 1
Article 3: name of article 3
Title 2: ...
Chapter 1: ...
...
Book 2:...
....
Book 3

---

So you get the idea, the text may contain the classification randomly, it's not like first all chapter, then all articles and so on.

The implementation proposed for this is:

```
 public class Book {
   private int id;
   private List<Chapter> chapters;
   private List<Title> titles;

   // getters/setters/constructor
}

public class Chapter {
   private int id;
   private List<Section> section;
   private List<Article> articles;

   // getters/setters/constructor
}

public class Title {
   private int id;
   private List<Chapter> chapters;

   // getters/setters/constructor
}

public class Section {
   private int id;
   private List<Article> articles;

   // getters/setters/constructor
}
```

The problem is that list must be created in a dynamic way. This is when the parser says I need a new list of chapters in the the book number n, I have to create it.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think map may be best choice than creating dynamic variables.

Comment: Ok, I heard of this solution but I don't know how a map works. The important thing here is that I'll need to know whether the element is a book or what and where in the structure it should be (which book is in, in which chapter and so on). I have to make a menu like: Choose a book and a list of chapters or titles depending on the book and then choose and so on until the article where I will show the text of the article. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to have them all implement an `Element` interface, then have the interface contain a reference to other `Element` objects:

```
public interface Element {
    List<Element> getSubElements();
}
```

Then Book:

```
public class Book implements Element {
    // Your other stuff
    private List<Element> subElements;

    public void getSubElements() {
        return subElements;
    }
}
```

[Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) at its best.

Comment: So you don't distinguish between chapters and articles right? But how do you put info in this structure and get it? Thanks, I'm new in java.